# Java 8 generate unique number pairs in order

Tags: java, functional-programming

I developed the code which can generate unique number pairs and it works fine

```
   Stream<String> stream = IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed().flatMap(a -> IntStream.range(0, 5).mapToObj(b -> a + ":" + b).distinct());
   stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
0:0
0:1
0:2
0:3
0:4
1:0
1:1
1:2
1:3
1:4
2:0
2:1
2:2
2:3
2:4
3:0
3:1
3:2
3:3
3:4
4:0
4:1
4:2
4:3
4:4
```

But how to generate the pairs so that output would look like

```
0:0
0:1
1:0
1:1
0:2
2:0
1:2
2:1
2:2
0:3
3:0
3:1
1:3
2:3
3:2
3:3
0:4
4:0
1:4
4:1
2:4
4:2
3:4
4:3
4:4
```

The idea is instead of generating first all pairs with `0` then with `1` and so on, I w'd like to generate pairs like `x:x x:y y:x y:y` and so on. Please provide answer only in `Java8` because for java  < 8 , I can easily write for loops and achieve it. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what order you want to get. Can you show the full output you want? What comes after 1:1?

Comment: @Eran Added the full expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a different ordering you can sort them as you generate them.

An approach might be to generate all the id's up to 0,1, 2,3, 4 etc.

This solution matches the order given

```
// 0 to 5-1 boxed so we can flatMap IntStream to Stream<String> later.
IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed()
        // generate pairs of ?::n and n::? or only one if the same.
        .flatMap(n -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n).boxed()
                 // generate the pair, dropping duplicates.
                 .flatMap(m -> Stream.of(m + ":" + n, n + ":" + m).distinct())
        // print the results.
        ).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Using `import static` it could look like this.

> range(0, 5).boxed().flatMap(n -> range(0, n+1).boxed().flatMap(m -> of(m + ":" + n, n + ":" + m).distinct()))
>   .forEach(out::println);

prints

```
0:0
0:1
1:0
1:1
0:2
2:0
1:2
2:1
2:2
0:3
3:0
1:3
3:1
2:3
3:2
3:3
0:4
4:0
1:4
4:1
2:4
4:2
3:4
4:3
4:4
```

---

This produces the requirements stated a different way.

```
// numbers 0 to 5-1
IntStream.range(0, 5)
         // make them boxed so we can do a flatMap to a Stream<String> later.
         // IntStream can't flapMap to a stream of Objects. 
         .boxed()
         // create two streams of ?::n and n::?
        .flatMap(n -> Stream.of(
                // stream is 0 .. n-1 to avoid duplicate n with next stream.
                // generate ?::n
                IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(m -> m + ":" + n),
                // stream is 0 .. n of n::?
                IntStream.rangeClosed(0, n).mapToObj(m -> n + ":" + m)
        // combine the two streams into one so that stream can be flatMappped.
        ).flatMap(s -> s))
        // print the results.
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
0:0
0:1
1:0
1:1
0:2
1:2
2:0
2:1
2:2
0:3
1:3
2:3
3:0
3:1
3:2
3:3
0:4
1:4
2:4
3:4
4:0
4:1
4:2
4:3
4:4
```

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible for you to describe the code in plain English?

Comment: @adam.kubi I thought it needed comments ;)

Comment: That's not the same order as requested in the question.

Comment: @Eran It matched the requirements in the words, but I have added a solution which is exactly the same order provided.

Answer (score 2):

This code works :

```
Stream<String> stream =
    IntStream.range(0, 5)
             .boxed()
             .flatMap(a -> IntStream.range(0, 5)
                                    .boxed()
                                    // keep only pairs where a>=b
                                    .filter(b-> {return a>=b;})
                                    // for each pair (a,b) , generate two pairs -
                                    // (b:a) and (a:b) 
                                    .flatMap(b -> Stream.of(b+":"+a,a+":"+b))
                                    .distinct());
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output :

```
0:0
0:1
1:0
1:1
0:2
2:0
1:2
2:1
2:2
0:3
3:0
1:3
3:1
2:3
3:2
3:3
0:4
4:0
1:4
4:1
2:4
4:2
3:4
4:3
4:4
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
        System.out.println("0;0");
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.println(j + ";" + i);
                System.out.println(i + ";" + j);
            }
            System.out.println(i + ";" + i);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but I am interested to see solution in Java8

Comment: This runs in Java 8 and is far easier to read than the sample code in your question.

Comment: But it doesn't use new features introduced in`Java8` and that's the whole point of asking the question.  Using Streams have more benefits then  traditional `for loop`

Comment: This is perfectly comprehensible. Simple thing stays simple. If adam.kubi explicitly didn't ask for Java8 answer, I would upvote this answer. Nevertheless, "functional" answers are great as an exercise.